# Solving $xy-(z+x)=zw-z-0.3x$ for $z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$w,x,$ and $y$ are user input variables.

So,

$(xy)-(z+x)=17.5$

and

$(zw)-z-0.3x=17.5$

$w=2, ~ y=2, ~ x=50, ~ z=32.5$

This is one instance.

The problem I have is that I need to solve for $z$ when any of the other variables are changed so that both equations have the same solution, presently $17.5$. Right now I have it set up so when a variable is changed I have to go in and manually manipulate $z$ until the two solutions match up. Meaning if you input $3$ for $w$ you end up with $17.5$ and $50$ as results. This now means $z$ has to equal $21.666$ and the equations both equal out to $28.33$... all because w was changed from $2$ to $3.$

Is there a way to automatically solve for $z$ so I don't have to go in and futz with numbers to make everything work out? I have it set up in Excel so it's not too hard to do manually, but it seems there should be a way for this to work a bit easier.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you asking how to solve $\,xy-(z+x)=zw-z-0.3x\,$ for $z$?

Comment: Are $z$ and $Z$ the same thing?

Comment: I guess that would be the answer... netting out z=x/w•(y-.7)... I was being a nitwit and not checking both sides. Meaning if you swap the inputs for w and y you get different answers... for some reason I was expecting the same output... like I said... nitwit. This does check out in the end.

z and Z are the same. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. You solve $xy- (z+x) = zw - z - 0.3x$ for $z$ and get $$z = \frac{x}{w} \cdot (y-0.7).$$

Comment: Thank you for the help.